# laravel Redirect from Controller to View when Login Success with Session not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, session, laravel-5

I'm new to Laravel 5.2 . I have been trying to create a login Page using Session and i wanted to redirect to another page when user login is successfull ...I validate users in Controller create Session and Redirect to a Success Page View but its not returning ...i tried to solve it but i am unable to do so ...the Controller is not returning the View success page ..am i doing it correctly or im missing something

```
<form id="loginForm">
  <div class="container">
    <label><b>Username</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="username" id="username" required>

    <label><b>Password</b></label>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="password" id="password" required>

    <button type="button" id="loginButton">Login</button>
    <input type="checkbox" checked="checked"> Remember me
  </div>

  <div class="container" style="background-color:#f1f1f1">
    <button type="button" class="cancelbtn">Cancel</button>
    <span class="psw">Forgot <a href="#">password?</a></span>
  </div>
</form>

</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('#loginButton').click(function(){
            //alert(SERVER_NAME);
            var formData = new FormData($('#loginForm')[0]);

            $.ajax({
              url : SERVER_NAME+"/api/userLogin",
              type :"POST",
              data :formData,
              processData: false,
              contentType: false,
              dataType :"json",
              beforeSend: function(){

              },               
              success : function(response)
              {

                console.log(response);
                //return false;
                  if(response.status==1){

                      alert(response.message);
                      // window.location.href = 'home';

                  }else{
                      alert(response.message);
                  }


              },
             complete:function(){


             }

            });  
        });

    });

</script>`
```

MY Controller

```
 public function userLogin(Request $request)
{
    $input = $request->all();
    //return $input;
    $userName=$input['username'];
    $password=$input['password'];
    //return $userName;
    $results = wowza::authenticate($userName,$password); 
    if (sizeof($results)>0){

         if($results[0]->email==$userName && $results[0]->password == $password)
            {
                Session::set('variableName', $userName);

                $results['status']=1;
                return \View::make('user.home')->with('results',$results);
                // return response()->json($results);
            }
    }

    return sizeof($results);

}
```

My Success Page

```
{{Session::get('variableName')}}
```

My Route

```
    Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('user.login');
});

Route::get('home', function () {
    //Session::get('username');
    return view('user.home');
});
$api->version('v1',function($api){
$api->post('userLogin','App\Http\Controllers\Api\V1\wowzaController@userLogin');
});
```

Comment: Is page not redirecting or your code is not reaching to the if block which sets the session?

Comment: page is not redirecting ,It reaches the if block @ParminderSingh

Comment: does this: Route::get('home', function () {
    //Session::get('username');
    return view('user.home');
}); also work?

Comment: When i open Home from browser it display the page and not the Session::get('username')..Its working but not through Return view(user.home),.the session is set if i return it and console.log.

Answer (score 0):

You can change at auth controller as 
protected $redirectTo = '/dashboard'; 
or
at route as 
Route::get('dashboard', function () { return redirect('your-path');
});       `

Comment: Sorry but i dont exactly get what u are suggesting @Tapan Barik

Answer (score 0):

Your page is not redirecting because you are loading the view file in your controller. Instead of this code:

`return \View::make('user.home')->with('results',$results);`

You should use redirect('home') method.

Let me know if that does not work.

Comment: i tried `return redirect('home')`,it does not return anything notthing is console `return redirect()->route('home');` gave me an Error internal server error @Parminder Singh

Comment: when i change the routes.php `Route::get('user\home', function () {
 //Session::get('username');
    return view('user/home');
});` it controller will return 404 error if i `return redirect('home')`, Maybe Controller is redirecting to correct route that is why its not consoling anything but from route 'return view(user.home)' is not triggered ...Trying to find a solution ...not solved yet y this is happening @Parminder singh

Comment: For me it worked fine:

`\Session::put('variablename', 'testing'); // I have laravel 5.4
return redirect('home');`

and in routes.php:
`Route::get('/home', function() {
 echo \Session::get('variablename');
 die;
});`

and it is redirecting fine.

Comment: im using 5.2. I think i might have to re install laravel . I dont understand y route is not returning the View ...after redirect from controller ...no error no nothing ..check log and there also nothing ...i might have config something  wrong ..Thanks any ways @Paraminder Singh im going to try like u did if it still fails the i will Re install ...